# Using DatePicker with no day picker

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, android-widget

I want to get a DatePicker Dialog with no day picker (only year and month) for credit cards expiration in a form.
I checked the DatePicker source code and it's not seem to be suporting such feature as not showing once of it's pickers.
Any other widget to do it or do i have to create my own widget **again**...

Comment: Since i see no answers even from android mailing lists, i gues there's no real way to do this.The alternative is simply taking google code for the date picker and it's counterpart dialog and enhance it (extending wont help, the bastards do eveything 'private' usualy so you can touch anything, duplicating code will have to be done here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just released an [alternative date picker framework](https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider) which allows you to create your own date and/or time dialog boxes. There is also an implementation of a date picker that you are asking for.

Comment: 10x :-) not 100% what i wanted but better than the default that's for sure, you just might have saved me lots f work :-)

Comment: The link you've given is broken.